# I'm overriding the original .focus() method. Is there any way for me to continue to do so, without breaking the original behavior

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

A few months ago i made a Javascript library for my work, and now it looks like it has a problem with the events handler, the problem is that i have a trigger events function by using the fireEvent method, that works great, and i have something like this:

```
["focus", "click", "blur", ...].each(function(e){
    MyEvents[e] = function(fn){
        if(!fn){
            trigger(element, e);
        } else {
            addEvent(element, e, fn);
        }
    }
});
```

Of course this is just an idea, the original function is lot bigger... well, as you can notice, i created a custom function for all standards events so i just call it like "element.click(function...); and so...

The problem is that now if i do "input.focus();" it doesnt get focus, but it trigger the event, how can i do so the element get actually in focus ?? maybe removing the focus from the array ?? and if i do so, will i have to remove some other events too like submit, blur, etc??

thank you, actually the library is being tested, so this bugs need to be corrected as soon as possible.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the element *in focus* - (that is, not triggering the event itself, but focus the element) you use the `.focus()` method.

You can't do that with the function listed above, because that only assigns events..

You just do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('#inputbox').focus();
```

yes, it's as simple as that

Of course, I have no idea how you're referencing the elements in the first place.

## after clarifications in the comments

I'm going to restate your question:
"I'm overriding the original .focus() method. Is there any way for me to continue to do so, without breaking the original behavior?"

Yes :)

Here's an example - because I don't know your variables or anything, I'm creating an element on the fly for this example - it's not required:

```
e = document.createElement('input');
document.body.appendChild(e);
// note: I'm using .focus() just because it was easier for me to debug.. you 
// just as well replace it with .blur() instead.
e.focus = function () {
    HTMLInputElement.prototype.focus.apply(this, arguments);
}    
e.focus();
```

JS Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/DK8M7/

Ok, I'm not sure how many of those variables you're familiar with. I'm giving an overview:

- `HTMLInputElement` is the name of the original object (think of it as a "class name") for all input elements
- `.prototype` is an object referencing a static object shared across all objects that have or have not been created yet. Kind of like an origin.
- `.apply()` is a method used to call a function from a specific context - that is, you choose it's "this" object, the latter argument is an array of it's parameters
- `arguments` is a special javascript array accessible from all functions which includes an array of all of it's parameters.

More on the apply method:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

## Overriding all input elements' blur() methods

One more thing... If you want *all* your input elements to have this behavior, the most simple way is to override it's prototype actually.. so since we're on this path, this is how you would do that:

```
HTMLInputElement.prototype.blurCpy = HTMLInputElement.prototype.blur;

HTMLInputElement.prototype.blur = function () {
    HTMLInputElement.prototype.blurCpy.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Cheers..

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that isnt working, i think its because i override the focus method with my function, so i can add a event handler. Element is just the object, like "getElementById('myInput'). Am i missing something maybe? or just missunderstanding everything? Thank you for your reply! Oh yeah, i didnt explained very well, that is a class that and then i extend the element with that function (the MyEvents object listed in my example) Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the function addEvent() - there is addEventListener() - is that what you were trying to do? Also, you can't override the .focus() function by adding an event listener to an element - the focus() method and the event (though also called focus) is not the same thing

Comment: The addEvent function is a custom function that basically calls the addEventListener and save an array with all the events and some more things, and about the focus() method, i know, i think i'm not being clear, im sorry. What i mean is that i have something like:  element.focus = function(fn){ ... }, which is the example above but for some standards elements. So when i do "element.focus()" it goes to my custom function, that's ok if i'm assigning an event listener, but i wanna set the focus to the field and i cant. Did i explained better now? thank you

Comment: ahh, I see. Well, it's generally bad practice to overwrite standard functions like that - Ok, I wrote a complex solution here in this edit box involving calling the original method and what not.. but really, I think you should either rename your function something else than .focus() (like .myFocus()) or make your version of the .focus() function call the original one..

Comment: Thats what i want to do, calling the original one so i can use mine or the original whenever i need it :D any idea? i think i asked everything wrong didnt i? thank you

Comment: You might have, but that's fine. It's hard to put abstract thoughts into words. I've updated my answer with your solution.

Comment: Excellent man, thank you!! i'll try to change the title (if possible) and add yours, from this sample functions i can go on now!! thanks, i just need to adapt it to my selector object and voila! Thank you again!

Comment: Hi arnorhs, Its really saved my time for implementing global blur method. Thanks, But i feel that some time when we focus on the text box the "HTMLInputElement.prototype.blur" getting fired. one more thing it is getting fired on all input elements, is there any way to restrict only to text/number inputs.

Comment: FYI it handles fine like JavaScript el.focus() calls, but is not executed when focused by keyboard or mouse click.